# Export CAD Layer Descriptions as attribute data in SHP format?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, convert, autocad-map

When exporting vector data from a CAD file (using Map3D), is anyone aware of a way to include the layer description? There seems to be a way to get all the other fields - lineweight, colour etc - but the description usually contains an english explanation of the CAD layer name. When CAD is added to ArcGIS Pro, I can see all the attributes **except** the description.

Comment: Layer description does not really belong to an attribute of a layer. It shows metadata that is common for the whole layer, but feature attributes are connected to individual features. You can add layer metadata with ArcGIS https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/metadata/view-and-edit-metadata.htm. A workaround could be to add a new attribute into the shapefile and write the layer description for each feature. Notice that the description cannot be longer than 254 characters that is the maximum that the .dbf part of a shapefile supports.